# prestashop 1.7 - how to set show_price for each product?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

How to do that for a specific product.
in fact i found that in an existing project, in some products the $product.show_price attribute is set to false. why and how is set ? is there a place in backend to set that attribute ? 
i already searched in the documentations and forums but didn't find a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your product go to the tab "Options" and uncheck a checkbox "Available for order" then you will see another checkbox "Show price".

Comment: this is exactly true